# What to do when instance is deleted from outside?

Tags: oop

I'm creating simple Warp simple for game called Minecraft.

Each warp will be represented with it's instance of class Warp. This class holds basic info like Location of this Warp, it's name, etc...

Class Warp holds static List which contains all created Warp instances and provides method to get any Warp by it's name (which is unique).

What should I do when warp is deleted via commands? Of course I will delete it from that static List, but there is problem that there could be some remaining references to that deleted Warp...

I have thought about creating something like isDeleted instance variable, so when I try to setLocation of this warp and isDeleted is true, it will do nothing and return boolean value of false - to indicate that new Location wasn't set... but that holds another problem - each time I use setLocation (or any other method) I would need to check whether that method returned true or false... which is not really efficient...

What is proper way to handle deleting of warp from outside?

Comment: What do you want to do when Warp is deleted? Do you want the classes using that Warp to stop using it and release the reference so that the object gets GCed?

Comment: Yeah something like that, because deleted Warp is not usable anymore... I'm asking, if it's enough for example to throw an exception if someone tries to manipulate with already deleted Warp... but even with exception - when any method of Warp class is called, that exception would need to be caught, so try-catch blocks would need to be used and this is really not good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there should be something like `WarpFactory` which should have the responsibility of tracking all Warp instances. In you case a map containing all the instances.

```
/*
 * This should be the only way you can get hold of an Warp object.
 */
class WarpFactory {
   private Map<String, Warp> warpNameToWarp = new HashMap<>();

   // Track the lifecycle listeners for notification
   private Multimap<String, WarpLifecycleListener> warpNameToListeners = new Multimap<>();

   /*
    * Ask for listener that will be client object to track the lifecycle
    * of Warp. If the warp gets deleted then we send notification to all 
    * the lifecycle listeners.
    */ 
   public Warp createWarp(WarpLifecycleListener listener) {
       Warp warp = createWarp();
       warpNameToWarp.put(warp.name(), warp);
       warpNameToListeners.put(warp.name(), listener);      
   }

   /*
    * When someone tries to get hold of warp instance we will ask for
    * a listener. The client implementation will have to delete the refernce
    * in response to deleted lifecycle event.
    */
   public Warp getWarp(String name, WarpLifecycleListener listener) {
      Warp warp = warpNameToWarp.get(name);
      // sanity check if warp is not known or already deleted.   
      warpNameToListeners.put(warp.name(), listener);
   }

   /*
    * When a warp is deleted from any interface then we will notify all the 
    * listeners about the deletion.
    */
    public void deleteWarp(String name) {
       Warp warp = warpNameToWarp.get(name);
       // sanity checks if warp does not exist

       // Notify the deletion of warp.
       for (WarpLifecycleListener listener : warpNameToListeners.removeAll(warp.name) {
          listener.warpDeleted();
        }
}
```

A lifecycle listener will have single method called `warpDeleted()` which makes it a good Functional Interface for use of lambda expression.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface WarpLifecycleListener {
    /*
     * A notification fired when a warp instance is deleted and no longer tracked
     * or useful. The implementors should release and no longer use the instance of  the warp to which the listener is attached.
     */
    void warpDeleted();
}
```

Client will ask `WarpFactory` for any operation related to `Warp`

```
class WarpClient {

    private Warp warp;

    ...
// Creating an instance of warp
   warp = warpFactory.createWarp(() -> {releaseWarp();});

   private void releaseWarp() {
      warp = null;
   }
}


class SomeOtherClient {
   private Warp warp;
// Getting a warp
   warp = warpFactory.getWarp(name, () -> {releaseWarp();});

}

class WarpDestroyer {

   // Destroys the warp
   warpFactory.deleteWarp(name); // This call will notify WarpClient and SomeOtherClient about the deletion so that they can release their instances.

}
```

Comment: Amazing solution, going to learn this technique soon! Thank you very much!